# Make only elements appears between mainmatter and backmatter on TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, front-matter, etoc, body

I use `etoc` package in `book` class and try to list only elements in mainmatter.

The chapters appearing before mainmatter or after backmatter shouldn’t appear.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the `tocdepth` counter appropriately.

```
% tocchapprob.tex  SE 649792

\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}} % nothing in ToC

\chapter{One front}
\section{uno}

\mainmatter
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{10}} % lots in ToC

\chapter{Two main}
\section{duo}

\backmatter

\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}} % nothing in ToC
\chapter{Three back}
\section{tres}

\end{document}
```